# Как отобразить математические выражения

Tags: c++, qt

Хочу отобразить математические формулы(TeX) в png(или какой то еще формат) в приложении на с++, qt и не могу найти работающие библиотеки для отрисовки.

к примеру

```
strinf str = "\int_{\Sigma}\!(\vec{\nabla}\times\vec u)\,d\vec S = \oint_C \vec{u}\cdot d\vec r";
```

затем вызов функции exec(str), который даст картинку

Посоветуйте что можно использовать?

Comment: Таки зачем Вам это надо? Вы хотите редактор формул вставить, если нет, то вставляйте формулы картинками, предварительно подготовив их в TeX. Зачем усложнять и накидывать в свою программу непонятные движки. А если Вы хотите редактор формул, то это прям сложная задача, вон в Ворде у Майкрософта до сих пор выходит какая-то ерунда.

Comment: @RomanOzhegov какую библиотеку использовать чтобы рисовать картинки?

Comment: так зачем использовать библиотеки, в TEX генерируете pdf-файл и оттуда printscreen забираете все что нужно с нужным разрешением.

Comment: @RomanOzhegov формулы меняются, формулы не статичны, мне нужно какое то средство чтобы отобразить красиво

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите сделать редактор формул, который в реальном времени Вам будет отрисовывать формулы. Я рекомендую Вам обратиться к опыту разработки ворда, libreoffice и прочих WYSIWYG-редакторов, где это до сих пор убого и коряво.

Comment: @RomanOzhegov не сколько редактор формул, сколько именно отображение формулы, к примеру считали из файла и отобразили в каком нибудь красивом виде

Comment: `KLFBackend` уже видел, но не осилил, я так понимаю? нум, гугл говорит ещё о [такой](https://github.com/NanoMichael/cLaTeXMath/tree/master/src) библиотечке...  как вариант, ещё можно использовать внешнюю программу...

Comment: Берем что-то типа MathURL, где ссылки на картинки имеют вид `http://mathurl.com/render.cgi?_формула_nocache`, и делаем соответствующие запросы, только формулу переводя в нужный для URL вид... Чем не решение? дешево и сердито :)